# installation of package 'RHmm_2.0.3.tar.gz' had non-zero exit status in R

Tags: r, macos, package, failed-installation

Actually, I would like to use the function “HMMFit” of package ”Rhmm”  in R, but it cannot find the package. Then, I try to download this package in https://cran.r-project.org/. The version is RHmm_2.0.3.tar.gz. When I install this package, it warning me that “installation of package ‘RHmm_2.0.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status”, and I cannot install it. I had search it in google, but I cannot find a useful solution. 
Do you have some suggestion?

Thanks

P.S. I am using RStudio verison 0.99.491, R version 3.2.3 and MAC OX.

Comment: What is the code you've used to try to install it that generates that error message?

Comment: I used "install.packages(RHmm)" and it alert me "Error in install.packages : object 'RHmm' not found". Then I download "RHmm_2.0.3.tar.gz" from the internet and install it in the RStudio right hand side, button "install".

Comment: `install.packages("path/to/file/RHmm_2.0.3.tar.gz", repos=NULL, dependencies=TRUE)` ... maybe that will work?

Comment: I have use that code before. 
"Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘~/Downloads/RHmm_2.0.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status"